# Reshape numpy array and stacking into 3D at regular intervals

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, numpy

I have some time ordered images stored as a numpy 2D array with the shape (60000, 784). I would like to ultimately reshape the data to (1200, 28, 28, 50). What I am trying to do is orient subsequent stacks the 50 28x28 images on top of one another where the top image is the earliest in time.

I think the following code is getting me started, but this returns a list of 1200 images of shape (50, 28, 28). I would like an numpy array that is of shape (1200, 28, 28, 50).

```
import numpy as np

X = np.ones((60000, 784))
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 28, 28)

X_new = []
prev = 0
for i in range(50, len(X)+50, 50):
    X_new.append(np.dstack( [X[prev:i]] ))
    prev += i

#print type(X_new)     # 'list'
#print len(X_new)      # 1200
#print X_new[0].shape  # (50, 28, 28)
```

Comment: Is there a problem when you use X.reshape(1200,28,28,50) ?

Comment: I am new to numpy, will `X.reshape(1200,28,28,50)` maintain the order of my images?

Comment: Yes, I'll add an answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to reshape the initial array and keep the images in order. For example:

```
# Get an array of length 60000, where each element is 784 numbers ranging from 1 to 60000 (so we can keep track)
X = np.outer(np.arange(1,60001,1),np.ones(784))

Y = X.reshape(1200, 28, 28, 50)
```

Checking:

```
Y[0] = [ 28x28 array of 1's, 28x28 array of 2's, ..., 28x28 array of 50's]
Y[1] = [ 28x28 array of 51's, 28x28 array of 52's, ..., 28x28 array of 100's]
Y[2] = [ 28x28 array of 101's, 28x28 array of 102's, ..., 28x28 array of 150's]
```

So you can see the images are stacked in groups of 50 that are in the correct order.

## Edit:

Thanks to comments, it should actually be:

```
Y = X.reshape(1200, 50, 28, 28)
```

To check this works:

```
X = np.outer(np.arange(1,60001,1),np.ones(784))
# Now let's change the first "image"
X[0] = np.arange(0,784,1)
Y = X.reshape(1200, 50, 28, 28)
```

We expect the first image in Y to be a 28x28 array where the first row is 0-27, the second row is 28-55 and so on. This is what we get so a transpose is not necessary.

```
Y[0][0] = [[1,2,...,27],
           [28,29,...,55],
           ...
           [756,757,...,783]]
```

Note: this is assuming the images are flattened row by row, i.e.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6   =>  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
7 8 9
```

Comment: Thank you! I was making that too complicated. Still have some learning to do, starting with trusting the Python gods...

Comment: Are you sure that `Y[0,:,:,0]` will look like a (28,28) image?  It think it needs a transpose.  `Y[0,0,;,:]` is (28,50) array of 1s.

Comment: Is @hpaulj not saying that it would then be necessary to transpose the axes even after swapping the order in the `reshape()`?

Comment: Thanks, @Robbie for the edit. That makes sense to me. Also, after running `X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 28, 28)` and testing to see if `Y[0][49] == X[50]` as well as other indices checks out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to transpose some axes after reshaping:

```
In [792]: X = np.ones((60000,784),int)
In [793]: X1 = X.reshape(1200,50,28,28)
In [794]: X2 = X1.transpose([0,2,3,1])
In [795]: X2.shape
Out[795]: (1200, 28, 28, 50)
```

An array of `ones` is not very diagnostic, and I'm not about to generate real images of this size.

---

Small test case:

```
In [796]: img = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [797]: img = img.flatten()
In [798]: img.shape
Out[798]: (12,)
In [799]: X = np.stack([img,img,img,img,img],0)
In [800]: X = np.stack([img,img,img,img,img,img],0)
In [801]: X.shape
Out[801]: (6, 12)
In [802]: X1 = X.reshape(2,3,3,4)
In [803]: X2 = X1.transpose([0,2,3,1])
In [804]: X2.shape
Out[804]: (2, 3, 4, 3)
In [805]: X2[0,:,:,0]
Out[805]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why do we need to transpose after reshaping? Is there a particular reason you chose the order `(1200,50,28,28)` in the second line?

Comment: Sorry, @hpaulj, you lost me a bit. Can you explain a bit more about what you are doing?

Comment: 1200*50=6000; 28*28=784.  If you split to (1200,28,28,50) you will scramble data points.  I'd suggest playing with a much smaller set of images.  What action retains the integrity of the images?  Why do you want the final dimension to be 50?

Comment: I am using the data to model changes in the images over time, which requires the groups of 50 images to be stacked on top of one another in sequential order. The choice of 50 is to test a hypothesis that the data undergoes some change within each subsequent 50 frames.